# Magento - Problems with embedding flash player in short description

Tags: javascript, html, magento

So, I've been trying to follow the directions at this link: http://www.macloo.com/examples/audio_player/

In an attempt to embed the flash player they link to and describe on a product in my Magento store.  I first read about the ability to use this flash player in the short description field for a Magento product from this discussion: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/32647/

Now, I've followed all the directions down to the letter (as far as I can tell) but the player simply does not work.  The player appears on my webpage, and appears to be functional, but when you click play the audio file just buffers forever and never plays.

What am I doing wrong?

You can see the embedded player on one of the products pages on my site here: http://soundcherry.com/index.php/ringtones.html

The files are stored on my host server at this location: public_html/media/audio

The files stored there are audio-player.js, player.swf, and robotic_birds.mp3.

In the short description field for my product, I have inserted the following code exactly:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.soundcherry.com/media/audio/audio-player.js"></script>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.soundcherry.com/media/audio/player.swf" id="audioplayer1" height="24" width="290">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.soundcherry.com/media/audio/player.swf">
<param name="FlashVars" value="playerID=audioplayer1&soundFile="http://www.soundcherry.com/media/audio/robotic_birds.mp3">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="menu" value="false">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your object tag does not seem to be valid, you can inspect using firebug, replace following:

```
<param name="FlashVars" value="playerID=audioplayer1&soundFile="http://www.soundcherry.com/media/audio/robotic_birds.mp3">
```

to

```
<param name="FlashVars" value="playerID=audioplayer1&soundFile=http://www.soundcherry.com/media/audio/robotic_birds.mp3">
```

notice the removed double quote after `soundFile=`

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick.  As a slight side note, I just noticed that the flash player isn't lined up properly with the add to cart button.  Is it possible to get the player to display inline with the add to cart button?